# Reference php are used when not

Tags: php, json, reference

I have one object variable `$datas` when I create another variable `$insertDatasInDatabase` and I assign it to `$datas` like this `$insertDatasInDatabase = $datas`. My element `$datas->form_data` is linked to `$insertDatasInDatabase->form_data`, I think its called reference and we initialize with `=&` but I **never** called a reference.

Here is my code :

```
$datas = json_decode($_POST['datas']);    
$datas->fill = 1;
$insertDatasInDatabase = $datas;
$insertDatasInDatabase->form_data = json_encode($insertDatasInDatabase->form_data);
var_dump($datas);
die();
```

My `var_dump` throw me `$datas->form_data` as json_encode or I never encode them. Any advice ?

Comment: See https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.references.php and https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.cloning.php.